# Выровнять две строчки по середине (по вертикали)?

Tags: html, css

Привет, как выровнять 2 строчки по середине по вертикали блока без display: table-cell?
Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/XXacE/

Comment: Прошу прощения сразу не написал: по вертикали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вроде как решение найдено: http://jsfiddle.net/rMGUR/
Но уж больно корявое, мб есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Вполне нормальное решение, что не нравится-то?